# "Declaration has no storage class or type specifier" error when using stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>

int coins = 0;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;
```

When I hover over `ss` I get the error "**declaration has no storage class or type specifier**" and when I hover over `<<` I get the error expected a `;`".

Comment: While you can have declarations like that (although you should strongly consider not having global variables), the *code* (`ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;`) needs to be inside a function.

Comment: This isn't your actual code is it?

Comment: No, but it's the only bit where there was an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not allow executable statements outside functions.

The first two lines are declarations; they are allowed, although I doubt that you made them global on purpose. The last line, however, must be placed inside a function, e.g. `main`:

```
int main() {
    int coins = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;
}
```

Comment: Made global on purpose, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

These can be outside of a function:

```
int coins = 0;
std::stringstream ss;
```

However this can't:

```
ss << 100 << ' ' << 200;
```

So, put it inside `main()` or any other function.